# qtnx delete session

Tags: linux, nx

From the graphical interface, when you connect to a host, it is possible to create a new session, but not to delete an existing one. Where is that information kept (in which file) in my computer, so that I can manually delete it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The files of each session are stored on the remote host in the hidden *.nx* directory in the owner home directory.
Usually you can find within the sub-directory *cache-gnome* or *cache.kde*, you can remove or rename these sub-directories in order to reset sessions.